# Calling a UIButton action from a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I dynamically created several buttons in my UITableviewCell class like so:

```
for (clientObjectId, _) in connectedObjectIds {
    self.clientNameButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    self.clientNameButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
    self.clientNameButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.leftSideSpaceForUsersAndUserLabel, clientNameButtonFrameHeight, self.nameButtonWidth, self.nameButtonHeight)
    self.clientNameButton.setTitle(self.userObjectIdsAndNames[clientObjectId], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.clientNameButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12.0)
    self.clientNameButton.addTarget(self, action: "asdf:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.nameButtons.append(self.clientNameButton)
    self.addSubview(self.clientNameButton)
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to call the following function in my table view cell class:

```
func asdf(sender:UIButton) {
     print("Button tapped")
}
```

I don't really care so much about being able to call it in my UITableViewCell class as much as my calling the function in my table view class.

Anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: pass self in addTarget.

Comment: self.clientNameButton.addTarget(self, action: "asdf:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

Comment: Oh my gosh. I'm so noob. I kicked myself in the butt for that one. Also anybody have any idea how I would call this `asdf()` function in my UITableView class instead of UITableViewCell class?

Comment: @Jae I think this is another question! :D no relation between this question.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Yea. You are right... Hahaha :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (clientObjectId, _) in connectedObjectIds {
    self.clientNameButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    self.clientNameButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
    self.clientNameButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.leftSideSpaceForUsersAndUserLabel, clientNameButtonFrameHeight, self.nameButtonWidth, self.nameButtonHeight)
    self.clientNameButton.setTitle(self.userObjectIdsAndNames[clientObjectId], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.clientNameButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12.0)
    self.clientNameButton.addTarget(self, action: "asdf:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.nameButtons.append(self.clientNameButton)
    self.addSubview(self.clientNameButton)
}
```